# Reading OleDb records into TextBox using ComboBox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, oledb

I'm new to programming. What i'm trying to accomplish is to fill in 9 textboxes in VB.NET, reading access table TblKlanten, using a combobox (CbbNaamfirma). I cannot get this to work for the life of me; i've been searching for 6 hours for this simple thing. Can any of you help me out? I've read numerous threads on SO.com like this and they all just won't work for me. 
Code i have now:

```
Private Sub CbbNaamfirma_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As           System.EventArgs) Handles CbbNaamfirma.SelectedIndexChanged
Dim Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database.accdb.'"
    Try
        Connection.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT Adres FROM TblKlanten WHERE [Naam firma] = ' " & CbbNaamfirma.Text & " ' "
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, Connection)
        Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
           TxtAdresprev.Text = Reader.GetString("Adres")
        End While
        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance. Hope that code block turned out alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to change is the reading from the database using a parameterized query. Notice that your code cannot find anything because you add a space before and after the value of the combobox.

Then you need to start employing the using statement around the disposable objects to ensure a proper closing and disposing

Finally the GetString method from the OleDbDataReader wants a numeric index inside the returned list of fields, not the name of the field

```
Private Sub CbbNaamfirma_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CbbNaamfirma.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                    Application.StartupPath & "\Database.accdb"
    Dim query = "SELECT Adres FROM TblKlanten WHERE [Naam firma] = ?"
    Using Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, Connection)
        Try
           Connection.Open()
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", CbbNaamfirma.Text) 
           Using Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
               While Reader.Read
                  Dim posAdres = Reader.GetOrdinal("Adres")
                  TxtAdresprev.Text = Reader.GetString(posAdres)
                  .... other text boxes for other fields here.....
              End While
           End Using

       Catch ex As OleDbException
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
       End Try
   End Using
   End Using
End Sub
```

Also your connection string seems to be wrong. No need of quotation and that stray point after the fielname is wrong

Comment: Sir, you have saved my life. How can i thank you in any meaningful way?

Comment: VoteUp requires 15 reputation...also, i have a new problem. i type in the remaining code for the text fields but all it shows is posAdres in TxtAdresprev.Text..what to do?

Comment: Please post a new question with the fixed code (Accepting and upvoting are two different things)